# Nesting Inheritance LNK2001 and LNK1120 error

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, lnk2001

My code isn't working. I'm trying simple inheritance Shape as base class and two classes under Shape "Two Dimension" and "Three Dimension" and shapes under that classes. Here's my code but when I try to define a new class as Triangle it gives me error LNK2001 LNK1120. It looks complicated but I must get area, volume and perimeter for every each object.
My full error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double __thiscall TwoDimensionShape::Area(void)" (?Area@TwoDimensionShape@@UAENXZ)  Shape   c:\Users\aleyn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Shape\Shape\Source.obj 1
```

That's .h

```
#pragma once
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
class Shape
{
private:
    double width, height, depth;
public:
    Shape(double w, double h, double d);
    virtual void Display() = 0;
    virtual double Area() = 0;
    virtual double Perimeter() = 0;
    virtual double Volume() = 0;
};

class TwoDimensionShape: public Shape
{
public:
    TwoDimensionShape(double w, double h, double d = 0) :
            Shape(w, h, d)
    {
    }
    double Area();
    double Perimeter();
    double Volume();
    void Display();
};

class ThreeDimensionShape: public Shape
{
private:
    double width, height, depth;
public:
    ThreeDimensionShape(double w, double h, double d) :
            Shape(w, h, d)
    {
        depth = d;
    }
    double Area();
    double Volume();
    double Perimeter();
    void Display();
};

class Triangle: public TwoDimensionShape
{
private:
    double side1, side2, base;
public:
    Triangle(double w, double h, double d = 0) :
            TwoDimensionShape(w, h, d)
    {
    }
    double Area()
    {
        return Area() / 2;
    }
    void setTriangleSides(double s1, double s2, double b);
    double Perimeter()
    {
        return side1, side2, base;
    }
    double Volume()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class Square: public TwoDimensionShape
{
public:
    Square(double w, double h, double d = 0) :
            TwoDimensionShape(w, h, d)
    {
    }
    double Volume()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class Rectangle: public TwoDimensionShape
{
public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h, double d = 0) :
            TwoDimensionShape(w, h, d)
    {
    }
    double Volume()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class Circle: public TwoDimensionShape
{
private:
    double radius;
public:
    Circle(double r, double a = 0, double d = 0) :
            TwoDimensionShape(r, a, d)
    {
        radius = r;
    }
    double Area()
    {
        return M_PI * (radius) * (radius);
    }
    double Perimeter()
    {
        return 2 * M_PI * radius;
    }
    double Volume()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class Sphere: public ThreeDimensionShape
{
private:
    double radius;
public:
    Sphere(double r, double a = 0, double b = 0) :
            ThreeDimensionShape(r, a, b)
    {
        radius = r;
    }
    double Volume()
    {
        return (4 / 3 * M_PI * (radius * radius * radius));
    }
    double Area()
    {
        return 4 * M_PI * radius * radius;
    }
    double Perimeter()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class Cylinder: public ThreeDimensionShape
{
private:
    double radius, height;
public:
    Cylinder(double r, double h, double a = 0) :
            ThreeDimensionShape(r, h, a)
    {
    }
    double Volume()
    {
        return M_PI * radius * radius * height;
    }
    double Area()
    {
        return (2 * M_PI * radius * height) + 2 * M_PI * radius * radius;
    }
    double Perimeter()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class Cone: public ThreeDimensionShape
{
private:
    double radius, height, side;
public:
    Cone(double r, double h, double s) :
            ThreeDimensionShape(r, h, s)
    {
    }
    double Volume()
    {
        return 1 / 3 * M_PI * radius * radius * height;
    }
    double Area()
    {
        return (M_PI * radius * side) + M_PI * radius * radius;
    }
    double Perimeter()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class RectPrism: public ThreeDimensionShape
{
public:
    RectPrism(double w, double h, double d) :
            ThreeDimensionShape(w, h, d)
    {
    }
    double Area();
    double Volume();
    double Perimeter();
};
```

my .cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Shape::Shape(double w, double h, double d)
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    depth = d;
}

double Shape::Area()
{
    return width * height;
}

double Shape::Perimeter()
{
    return (width + height) * 2;
}

double Shape::Volume()
{
    return width * height * depth;
}

double ThreeDimensionShape::Area()
{
    return (2 * (height * width) + 2 * (depth * width) + 2 * (depth * height));
}
double ThreeDimensionShape::Volume()
{
    return width * height * depth;
}
double ThreeDimensionShape::Perimeter()
{
    return (4 * width + 4 * height + 4 * depth);
}

void Triangle::setTriangleSides(double s1, double s2, double b)
{
    side1 = s1;
    side2 = s2;
    base = b;
}

void TwoDimensionShape::Display()
{
    cout << "Perimeter: " << Perimeter() << endl;
    cout << "Area: " << Area() << endl;
    cout << "Volume: " << Volume() << endl;
}
```

main .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Shape.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Triangle t1(8, 5, 0);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you gotta show the full error message

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why Is your `Shape` constructor assigning to members in the constructor body rather than using the initialisation list?

Comment: `#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846` - huh? `M_PI` is already defined in the `<cmath>` header. Why do you need your own definition?

Comment: i just simply put everything i saw here about my errors to the code, which is why it's a mess.

Comment: "unresolved external symbol ..." So, you need to link with whatever object file or library that defines/implements the symbol in question.

Comment: The error messages on the Output tab are often better than the truncated versions in the Error List tab. Plus the Output tab is easier to copy-paste into Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: I find myself thinking that `TwoDimensionShape::Area` and friends should remain pure virtual. It's not like `TwoDimensionShape` has enough specific information to supply a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

the error message says it all

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double __thiscall TwoDimensionShape::Area(void)"
```

You have not written `TwoDimenionalShape::Area`

In your header file you promised to write one, but you didnt

Comment: In this case it's better to remove the promise and NOT write this function. `TwoDimensionShape` doesn't have the information required to compute area. Leave that job to classes derived from `TwoDimensionShape` that do know how to compute area.

Comment: but couldn't i use it as it is in the Shape::Area(), if i should re-define it what's the point of the inheritance?

Comment: @notacomputer If `TwoDimensionShape` does not define `Area` you will not be able to instantiate a `TwoDimensionShape`, but since it is still too abstract to do anything useful on its own you should not be able to instantiate one, and the requirement for `Area` will fall through to classes derived from it. You will be able to invoke `Area` on a  `Shape` or any derived classes. Once a function is defined to be in a class, all subclasses have that function whether they override it or not.